# Exterior power of a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Suppose $M$ is a free R module where $R$ is commutative and unital. Is $\Lambda^n M$, the nth exterior power of $M$ free?

Comment: I ask this because I was discussing with someone that this is the case since we know that $\Lambda^n M$ has a basis with $^nC_{l}$ elements where $l$ is the rank of $M$. However they insisted that it was not that simple.

Comment: There's a mild difficulty where you need to make sure your definition does the right thing in characteristic $2$. If you're not careful you'll get the symmetric rather than the exterior power.